# Ошибка docker в phpstorm

Tags: docker, phpstorm

Установил Docker Toolbox for Windows
При попытке связать его в phpstorm получаю ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Папка c:\Users\Александр.docker\machine\machines\default\ на диске С присутствует вместе с файлами. Но ошибка, по всей видимости, возникает когда он пытается перекодировать папку с именем Александр, получает кракозяблы и кидает мне ошибку. Как быть в этой ситуации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переключись на TCP socket.
В Engine API URL впиши:

```
https://192.168.99.100:2376
```

Папку сертификатов укажи: `C:\Users\Александр\.docker\machine\machines\default`